# How bit precision while training can impact DNN's accuracy - Libraries that would support inference with quantized types

Tags: python, deep-learning

I would like to check how bit precision impacts DNN's accuracy. Do you know any C/C++/Python libraries
that wouldn't require huge rework for supporting inference with quantized types? For example, I would like to set all the operands (weights, activations, errors and gradients) to 8/16/32 bit precision and check accuracy for each precision after testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PyTorch (Python) you can set the dtype of your tensors e.g.:

```
torch.tensor(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]), dtype=torch.HalfTensor)  # 16 bit FP
```

It supports most dtypes, see the docs [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html)
Note that not all GPUs support all dtypes so you probably should stick to CPU execution.

EDIT:

To cast layers: `nn.Linear(10, 10).double()` or to set default dtype `torch.set_default_dtype()` [ref](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-set-dtype-for-nn-layers/31274)

Comment: So if inputs to my model, are tensors with ```dtype = torch.float16```, PyTorch makes sure that weights, activations, errors and gradients are tensors with the same dtype as inputs?

Comment: Edited the answer, you have to cast the layers explicitly, or manually set the `Parameter` tensor of a layer (`nn.Module`). Gradients and everything should then follow due to autograd. The nice thing is you can actually check everything manually while executing using standard python `type`. That's one of the niceties of PyTorch.